isn't defined for the class 'HardwareKeyboard'
There is dependancy mismatch and give following error by flutter syncfusion calender function widget.

'HardwareKeyboard' is from 'package:flutter/src/services/hardware_keyboard.dart' ('../../../../development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/hardware_keyboard.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'isShiftPressed'.
if (HardwareKeyboard.instance.isShiftPressed &&
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/syncfusion_flutter_datepicker-26.1.39/lib/src/date_picker/date_picker.dart:10335:35: Error: The getter 'isControlPressed' isn't defined for the class 'HardwareKeyboard'.
'HardwareKeyboard' is from 'package:flutter/src/services/hardware_keyboard.dart' ('../../../../development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/hardware_keyboard.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'isControlPressed'.
if (HardwareKeyboard.instance.isControlPressed) {
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Here is the Pubspec.yaml
version: 1.0.0+1
environment:
sdk: '>=3.2.3 <4.0.0'
dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter
http: ^0.13.3
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
hooks_riverpod: ^2.4.10
flutter_hooks: ^0.20.5
riverpod_annotation: ^2.3.4
flutter_riverpod: ^2.4.10
riverpod: ^2.5.0
email_validator: '^2.1.16'
flutter_secure_storage: ^9.0.0
intl: ^0.19.0
geolocator: ^11.0.0
flutter_local_notifications: ^17.1.2
image_picker: ^0.8.4+8
flutter_typeahead: ^3.1.2
table_calendar: ^3.1.2
fl_chart: ^0.68.0
syncfusion_flutter_calendar: ^26.1.39
What is the compatible version with above dependancies

This might be caused by different causes, the following are the common solutions:
You have a lot of outdated packages!
Try flutter pub outdated then replace them to their latest version.
If it doesn't work, try flutter upgrade to upgrade your flutter sdk version to the last flutter stable channel version...
